# Why does my progress bar not working properly?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've been building an app which has Log In functionality. I've tested it but every time i tried to Log In, the progress bar disappeared to quickly (like a quarter second or something), and the response i get from the server is like about 2 seconds after the progress bar disappeared. Here are some of my codes.

**My LoginTask inner class :**

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Account, Void, Account>{
        private String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
        private String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //showDialog();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Account account) {
            super.onPostExecute(account);
            //dismissDialog();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Account doInBackground(Account... accounts) {
            getLogin(getUsername, getPassword);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Login Retrofit call to server**

```
private void getLogin(String email, String password) {
        Call<LoginAuth> call = userService.getLogin(email, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginAuth>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginAuth> call, Response<LoginAuth> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.body().getToken_type().equals("xxx")) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "getLogin, Authorized access");
                        Log.i(TAG, "getLogin, access_token: " + response.body().getAccess_token().toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "getLogin, expires_at" + response.body().getExpires_at().toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "getLogin, Unauthorized access" + response.body().getToken_type().toString());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getLogin exception " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginAuth> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getLogin, onFailure : " + t.getMessage());
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to Log In :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I want it to work like when the response is fetched, that's the time the progress bar disappeared (not instantly). Did i do something wrong with the code?

Comment: you are doint async call inside async task. That's why your `doInBackground` finishes immediately. Either use `AsyncTask`, or `call.enqueue`

Comment: Remove Async Task. Call getLogin() method directly.

Comment: Else you can add a delay of 2-3 secs

Comment: i have tried do it in call and i works perfectly. Thank you for all of your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using retrofit, there is no necessity to call your api in separate asynctask as retrofit manages it asynchronously. what you should do is show your progressbar before you call api and dismiss it in `onResponse` and `onFailure` both. so your code would change to something like below.

```
private void getLogin(String email, String password) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Call<LoginAuth> call = userService.getLogin(email, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginAuth>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginAuth> call, Response<LoginAuth> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                //rest of your code
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginAuth> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getLogin, onFailure : " + t.getMessage());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                //rest of your code
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have done it and it works perfectly. Thank you for your answer! :)